# connect with Remote Server

Tags: php, mysql

When I connect to the database it give me an error.

Here is my code:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '27.98.50.159';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username here';
$db['default']['password'] = 'my pass here';
$db['default']['database'] = 'my db name';
```

My files are on another server and my database is on another.

How I connect when I give IP of server it give an error .......

[image]

Comment: instead of `$db['default']['hostname'] = '27.98.50.159'; ` try `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>'; ` If no pot number required simply localhost

Comment: Is your network traffic open and also check if the mysql service is up on the other server.